# How to print css of a table

Tags: jquery, css

I need to get the table printed along with it's css using jQuery. I have included @media print section in my css file. But when i click the print button, in print preview it only displays basic html layout.

Following is the Html:

```
<div>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="clo1">
                <td>bill</td>
                <td>gates</td>
                <td>51</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="clo2">
                <td>larry</td>
                <td>page</td>
                <td>61</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="clo3">
                <td>steve</td>
                <td>jobs</td>
                <td>71</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="printMe">
        <button id="print" type="submit">
            Print
        </button>
    </div>
```

Following is my Css:

```
@media print {

th, td {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
}
tr {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
td {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 3px;
}
th {
    background-color: #D2E0E8;
    color: #003366
}
table {
    border: 1pt solid gray;
    text-align: center;
}
}


@media screen {

th, td {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
}
tr {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
td {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 3px;
}
th {
    background-color: #D2E0E8;
    color: #003366
}
table {
    border: 1pt solid gray;
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

Following is my script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".printMe #print").click(function() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=auto,height=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write($('#myTable').html());
    popupWin.print();
    popupWin.document.close();
});
});
```

Comment: ...usually the print styles overwrite the main styles, so it would be a good idea to declare the `@media print` after the `@media screen`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Answer (score 1):

Create two separate CSS files. One for @media screen. Underneath that, create a new CSS file for @media print. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print" />
```

Screen CSS:

```
/* Normal screen CSS (no @media required) */
```

Print CSS:

```
@media print { }
```

Always works for me! 
Good luck!

Comment: There is no need to specify  `@media print { }` inside a stylesheet linked with `media="print"`

Answer (score 1):

You're opening a brand new window which doesn't have any reference to your stylesheet. Try this:

```
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" href="print.css"></head><body>');
popupWin.document.write($('#myTable').html());
popupWin.document.write('</body></html>');
```